# Is logistic regression capable of simple speech recognition that detect 2 words from each other?

Tags: regression, logistic, natural-language

Is logistic regression capable of detecting 2 words like "yes" or "no" given input waveforms or do I need something more complicated like HMM?

My goal is just to control an arduino motor with voice command on and off

Comment: I am curious about what variables you intend to use to classify the words. This seems like a real-time online decision process, which by its nature would not have a fixed set of variables.

Comment: Umm, I was going to use the top n frequency spectrum as my feature and use it to train the hyperplane, I am not sure how well logistic regression works with sound, but ideally the variable set should be fix within a given error right? For example if my frequency spectrum for "yes" is [1, 2, 3, 4], if I train my data to accept a range within [1 + delta, 2  + delta, 3 + delta, 4 + delta] I should be able to get an ok classification result? I might be completely wrong, hence the question.

Comment: If your $g(\mu)$ is sufficiently close to linear in your features or some transform of them, then yes, it should be possible. The degree of success you have in practice will tend to relate to how good your features are -- logistic regression won't itself choose them for you.

Comment: Awesome, I am going to test it with mfcc, thanks for the response